# Local network proxy/spoof

Tags: network, vulnerability-scanners, network-scanners

Are intruders in a local network able to mask their local IP in any way?
Could they 'hijack' another local IP and perform scans and exploits from there?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.

One way to go would be with ARP spoofing. It can be used to put your node as a gateway for the network.

Answer (score 0):

Funny you ask that, I've been doing tests on that and the only thing I was able to spoof was the mac-address in Linux Backtrack such that I was able to tell my switch that I am another PCs mac address but NOT IP address such that I could see all the data being sent to the other PC and go on undetected (Man in the middle attack). You can however mask your public address using HideMyIp , a certain software I came across the piratebay. You can also use the TOR browser bundle. If you want to verify that HideMyIP or the TOR browser bundle are working go to [1](http://www.whatismyip.com) [What Is My IP] and it can tell you your location. Download hide my ip from [2](http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/7580939/Hide_My_ip_5.3_time_reseter) [Hide My IP]. The tor bundle [3](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en) [TOR] . So it most definitely is quite possible unless all ports / sharing is blocked on your network.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set your up address as static and then change your Mac address to match that of the real hardware at that ip but I have not tried this and dont know how it would work in practice.. could create some interesting results when it comes to port jacking etc.